# How to map embeddable that contains many-to-many

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following DB schema:

[image]

And the following model:

[image]

I'm struggling to map the `RootChildren` as an `@Embedded` within `Root`. I've tried using a `@ManyToMany` within `RootChildren` to map the set of `Child`, but I couldn't make it work.
It doesn't seem like there's a lot of documentation online on the subject or at least I couldn't find
anything that works so hopefully someone will be able to help.

Note that I do not want to model bi-directional relationships if possible. Thanks!

<sup>*Erratum: `RootChildren#children` should be a `SortedSet`.*</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I did the following mapping in a scratch project I have (running on embedded Derby, but that should not matter) and it seems to work. I *did* have problem defining the collection as `SortedSet`, hibernate complained that "A sorted collection must define and ordering or sorting"; it would go away if I added an ordering property (visible to the state of the entity), which is not what you want.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="SO_ROOT")
public class Root {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    @Embedded
    private RootChildren children;

    // getters and setters
}
```

```java
@Embeddable
public class RootChildren {
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "SO_ROOT_CHILDREN",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "root_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
    )
    @OrderColumn(name = "xorder")
    private List<Child> children;

    // getters and setters
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="SO_CHILD")
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Test code:

```java
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = ...
            em.getTransaction().begin();

            Root root1 = new Root();
            Root root2 = new Root();
            Child r1c1 = new Child();
            Child r1c2 = new Child();
            Child r2c1 = new Child();
            Child r2c2 = new Child();
            RootChildren rc1 = new RootChildren();
            rc1.setChildren(Arrays.asList(r1c1,r1c2));
            RootChildren rc2 = new RootChildren();
            rc2.setChildren(Arrays.asList(r2c1,r2c2));
            root1.setChildren(rc1);
            root2.setChildren(rc2);

            em.persist(root1);
            em.persist(root2);

            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        finally {
            EntityManagerUtil.safeClose(em);
        }
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll try that as soon as I can. For now I made `RootChildren` an entity from the persistence perspective, but it's not ideal. Do you know if it will also work if I have a collectoin of `RootChildren` in `Root`? Probably mapped with `ElementCollection` or something like that, because that's the design I need after all (although I know it's a different question, sorry).

Comment: I *think* it should work. It would roughly require you to make it an `@ElementCollection` and move the annotations from the `@Embeddable` to `Root`. Maybe it needs some more silly tweaking :)

Comment: In theory, you cannot have an embedded collection of elements containing another embedded collection. But I didn't expect this mapping to work as well... so I might be wrong.

Comment: @Davide Hmmm, I may have gotten the question in the comment wrong - or made too many assumptions. I *assumed* that what @plalx wants is `Root` to have a `Collection<RootChildren>`, but then the `RootChildren` has *a single* `Child`. If the `RootChildren` have many `Child` objects, it wouldn't make sense, and it may even be illegal, as you suggest.

Comment: Maybe I'm the one who didn't understand :)

Comment: At least now every option is explained

Comment: `RootChildren` would need a collection of `Child` as well when `Root` has `Collection<RootChildren>`. It's basically a list of lists and I think something would have to be turned to an entity because JPA doesn't support that right? I'm basically modeling multiple selections of a hierarchy of categories.

E.g.

{
    selections: [
        ["IT", "Computers"],
        ["Colors", "Red"]
    ]
}

IT & Computers are actually entity references though and not just primitives. From what I can see JPA is not very friendly when it comes to modeling complex "value" graphs.

Answer (score 1):

`Child` cannot be an entity if you want to use embeddables.

You can map `RootChildren` as separate entity with a composite key containing `Root` and `Child` as a `@ManyToOne` association:

```
@Entity
@IdClass( PK.class )
public static class RootChildren {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Root root;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Child child;

    int ordering;

}

public class PK implements Serializable {

    private Root root;

    private Child child;

    public PK(Root root, Child child) {
        this.root = root;
        this.child = child;
    }

    private PK() {
    }

    //Getters, setters, hashcode and equals are omitted for brevity
}
```

Alternatively, if you create a separate class like `EmbeddedChild`, you could use this mapping:

```
@Entity
class Root {

  @Embedded
  RootChildren children;
}


@Embeddable
class RootChildren {

   @ElementCollection
   Set<EmbeddedChild> children;
}

@Embeddable
class EmbeddedChild {

}
```